# androidx with databinding error: package android.support.constraint does not exist

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack, androidx

I'm just learning about `databinding` and tried to use the new library structure as `androidx`.
When I tried to build the project I'm facing this error.

> error: package android.support.constraint does not exist

This error is in the Binding generated file as

```
public class ActivityMainBindingImpl extends ActivityMainBinding  {
    @Nullable
    private static final androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.IncludedLayouts sIncludes;
    @Nullable
    private static final android.util.SparseIntArray sViewsWithIds;
    static {
        sIncludes = null;
        sViewsWithIds = null;
    }
    // views
    @NonNull
    private final android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout mboundView0;
    @NonNull
    private final android.widget.TextView mboundView1;
```

Here is my `build.gradle` app module.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.climesoft.learn.livedatabinding"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}
```

Here is `build.gradle` project module.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the final `gradle.properties` file is this.

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

So why android studio not generating the Binding class with `androidx.constraintlayout` package?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`android.support.constraint` means you're using support library instead of AndroidX.

You probably should change `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` to `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` in the `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: Same error with same library but now work in my case

Comment: This solved my problem after Android Studio update 3.2.x -> 3.6.1 and subsequent Gradle update to 5.6.4 . I had also to replace all other `android.support.constraint.xxx` elements with corresponding elements from `androidx`.

Answer (score 0):

With androidx, the package names have changed. What was android.support is now androidx. Normally, AndroidStudio changes that automatically, when you convert your project to androidx/jetpack. There is an option for that in the Build... menu somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:x.x.x
```

try to change:

```
implementation 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:master-SNAPSHOT'
```